# Implementation of an nxn matrix using a single record

Tags: java

To start off, I would like to know what exactly is a record in comparison to an array? From what I'm trying to understand from my textbook, "Gilles Dowek, Principles of Programming Languages", it's almost like an array but needs labels and values associated to these labels. The example given is:

labels: {latitude, longitude, altitude}

record: {latitude = 48.715, longitude = 2.208, altitude = 156}

What also confuses me is how one implements this 2-D matrix with a single record (which I assume is a single row vector like the example above).

I have only a year experience with programming in general so any sort of readings or sources with a descriptive answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `record` doesn't have any precise technical meaning in Java. Java has arrays and objects. The closest to what you posted is an object with three fields latitude, longitude and altitude.

Comment: Record does not sound familiar for the java language. I think to remember that record is pascal terminology (also see here http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/javanotes3/c8/s1.html ). My advice is that since you plan to do your square matrix in java you should use a dedicated java textbook ( a free german online java book can be found here http://openbook.galileocomputing.de/javainsel/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, (with the resources provided in the comments to my question) a record is  simply a Java object that has instance variables, but no instance methods. Using this knowledge, an array is very different from a record. The comparison would essentially be between an object class and an array.

Implementing a 2-D matrix, or more specifically, visually implementing the matrix so it looks like a square when printed is not the record's job, as this would require instance methods which isn't part of a record.

The solution to implementing an nxn matrix using a single record would simply be initializing "n times n" instance variables within a class. In general, the solution to making any record would be to initialize any required number of instance variables within a class.

Answer (score 0):

Array can only store values which you can access by indices, while record assigns one label to one value (you can access value using a key).

You can use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to store multiple records with different keys, example:

```
HashMap<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("latitude", 48.715);
map.put("longitude", 2.208);
map.put("altitude", 156.0);
```

Then, when you want to get a value:

```
double latitude = map.get("latitude");
```